# How can I limit the number of characters returned by a String field when querying a GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql

When querying a GraphQL API, a String column can contain thousands of characters. I only want to return the first thousand.

How can I limit the number of characters returned by from a String field to the first 1,000 characters when querying a GraphQL API?

Comment: customize resolver, pass variable/parameter

Comment: Is that something the API consumer can implement, or does the author of the API have to customize the resolver?